# Why can't I submit my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a modal popup, that I want to hide when the 'shade' is clicked, but not when the contents are clicked. For this purpose I have:

```
$('#shade').click(function(){
  $('#shade').fadeOut();
}).children().click(function(e){
  return false;
});
```

The problem is I have a form inside that I want to submit, and this code prevents the form from submitting, so I have:

```
$('#shade-form-submit').click(function(){
  document.getElementById('shade-form').submit();
});
```

However this results in the following error in the console:

```
[13:07:21.145] TypeError: document.getElementById(...).submit is not a function @ ...
```

What's going on? For reference, my `<form>` tag:

```
<form action='.' method='post' id='shade-form'> 
  <div>
    <input type='text' />
  </div>
  <div>
     <div>
       <input type='submit' />
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's odd that you're using `document.getElementById` when you have jQuery that can help you. You can rely on native methods rather than jQuery for performance intensive DOM tasks, but that's not the case.

Comment: @MaxArt I've only got that in because jQuery wasn't working!

Comment: You could have added that. What does `document.getElementById` return? Your form, `null` or maybe another element that's actually not a form?

Comment: @MaxArt It returns the correct `HTMLFormElement`, but still complains that `submit` is not a function.

Comment: Sounds odd. Have you tested it at runtime? What does `typeof` say about the `submit` property? And what does it yield converting it to a string? Have you tried it with different browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exclude form inputs from the click handler you have on `children()`:

```
$('#shade')
    .click(function(){
        $('#shade').fadeOut();
    })
    .children().not(':input').click(function(e){
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: This works, but I have two `input`s at different depths (a text field and the submit button), and I can't get it to exclude both at the same time, only one or the other. I've put the DOM structure in the question. Any tips?

Comment: @TomMedley - test the event's actual target for the type of element, or use a delegated event handler instead of binding a click handler to all `children()`